# Product Method - Order Item Hash in return URL

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way that you can return a hash of the order line as part of the "Add to basket" button?

For example,

`/basket/added/ORDER_ITEM_HASH`

Then, it would be great if on the page you can find the order item by this hash and show the user an informative notification rather than a simple "Added to basket" message.

> You have added the **Acme 3000** to your basket with the following options:-
>
> - Colour: Red
> - Size: Large
> - Qty: 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it exactly like you're asking.

Perhaps you could add a `{exp:store:cart}` tag at the top where you want to display the message and inside the `{items}` loop, use a conditional to only show the last item added. Something like this

```
{exp:store:cart}
    {items}
         {if item:count == item:total_results}
            display item
         {/if}
    {/items}
{/exp:store:cart}
```

Comment: That's a pretty clever solution - I'll give it a go first thing in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: Why thank you :) Hopefully it works ok. I'm not sure if it has performance implications with lots of queries or anything.

Comment: Good idea! You could also match on the `entry_id` or `url_title` if you want to show any previous versions of this item already added.